# Parse date with month name in Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have to parse in Joda Time this exact string: "june 15 2015" and compare it with another date of the same format: "september 15 2015".
How can I do that? I'm not able to get working that date syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a pure Joda answer:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate d1 = dtf.parseLocalDate("june 15 2015");
LocalDate d2 = dtf.parseLocalDate("september 15 2015");
System.out.println(d1.isBefore(d2)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert it to `Timestamp`, use samething like this

```
 //date1 : your first date
 //date2 : your second date
 //sdf : date format 

        java.util.Date utilDate1 = new java.util.Date(date1);
        java.util.Date utilDate1 = new java.util.Date(date2);

        java.sql.Timestamp ts1 = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate1.getTime());  
        java.sql.Timestamp ts2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate2.getTime());  

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");

        if(sdf.format(ts1)>sdf.format(ts2))
            System.out.println("date1 > date2");
        else
          System.out.println("date1 < date2");
```

Comment: Why?  `java.util.Date` carries date/time information, if anything, you don't want the time component at all, besides, you've not parsed the `String` value to a `Date` value...?